# What is the problem in this code? I am getting a problem in this piece of code

Tags: python, placeholder

```
a = float(input("Enter first number: "))
b = float(input("Enter second number: "))
print('The product of {first} and {sec} is: ',a*b).format(first = a, sec = b)
print('The sum of {first} and {sec} is: ',a+b).format(first = a, sec = b)
```

Something of **AttributeError** is coming. Can you guys fix this, Need it for school project.

I tried this `placeholder` from [https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_string_format.asp]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The order of your parameters is wrong:

```
a = float(input("Enter first number: "))
b = float(input("Enter second number: "))
print('The product of {first} and {sec} is: '.format(first=a, sec=b), a*b)
print('The sum of {first} and {sec} is: '.format(first=a, sec=b), a+b)
```

Or for better understanding:

```
a = float(input("Enter first number: "))
b = float(input("Enter second number: "))
txt_prod = 'The product of {first} and {sec} is:'
txt_sum = 'The sum of {first} and {sec} is:'
print(txt_prod.format(first=a, sec=b), a*b)
print(txt_sum.format(first=a, sec=b), a+b)
```

However, it would be better to use [`f-strings`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#formatted-string-literals):

```
a = float(input("Enter first number: "))
b = float(input("Enter second number: "))
print(f'The product of {a} and {b} is: {a*b}')
print(f'The sum of {a} and {b} is: {a+b}')
```

Output:

```
Enter first number: 12
Enter second number: 4
The product of 12.0 and 4.0 is: 48.0
The sum of 12.0 and 4.0 is: 16.0
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you have the .format in the wrong place.  It needs to be inside the printf(), not attached behind it.

It would be better to use f-strings:

```
print(f'The product of {a} and {b} is: {a*b}')
print(f'The sum of {a} and {b} is: {a+b}')
```